# regex match only "Group 1." and not "Full match"

Tags: regex, grep

Hi I have the following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/wJ9yS6/147) that **should** return me the content of **only** what is between the 9nth and 10nth **vertical bar ( | )**

`^\d*,MSH(?:[^|]*\|){9}([^|]*)`

But it returns me "Group 1." and "Full match":
[image]

When I use linux grep with the regex `grep -P '^\d*,MSH(?:[^|]*\|){9}([^|]*)' export.csv`
it selects the "Full match":

```
16037,MSH|^~\&|SENDAPP|SENDFAC|RECVAPP|RECVFAC|1||ORU^R01|78455-874-6875|P|2.3|||AL
```

**How can I make grep** to print only the `Group 1.` `78455-874-6875`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using the `-P` option the easiest solution is to truncate the match after you matched the text up to the 9th pipe with [`\K` match reset operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html):

```
grep -oP '^\d*,MSH(?:[^|]*\|){9}\K[^|]*' file
                                ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZ7Fuc/1)

A [`grep` online demo](https://ideone.com/orl6mi):

```
s='16037,MSH|^~\&|SENDAPP|SENDFAC|RECVAPP|RECVFAC|1||ORU^R01|78455-874-6875|P|2.3|||AL'
grep -oP '^\d*,MSH(?:[^|]*\|){9}\K[^|]*'  <<< "$s"
# => 78455-874-6875
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the  wrong tool for the job. This will work clearly, simply, efficiently, portably, and extensibly with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ awk -F'[|]' '/^[0-9]*,MSH/{print $10}' file
78455-874-6875
```

Any time you have input that's broken up into fields or requires compound regexps you should seriously consider using awk instead of grep.